Name of a 4 pin squared fan connector
I'd like to build a custom board to control the fans of a Dell poweredge r720, and they use a 4-pin connector that I couldn't find any information about it. Here's the board connectors:


Here's the fan for reference (but I need the female part):

Thanks.
Edit: the distance between pins looks like it's ~2.5mm.

Try to find out the pitch (pin-to-pin distance) using calipers. Could it be a plain old 2.54mm (0.1'') box header 2x2?

"Here's the fan for reference (but I need the female part):" That is a female part. Holes = vagina = female.  Do you need the male (4 pins) or the female (4 sockets)? Also, we need the exact pitch, please.

@DavideAndrea oh I guess that's confusing because one has pins, but the holes go into a bigger hole... I need the ones in the PCB, to plug the fans into it.

@Lundin I tried my best... something arround 2.5mm

Also, the server is 13 years old, so it should be an old connector

Can you find a part number on it?

@AndrewMorton You mean a serial number for the socket? If you're talking about the fan it's this model: https://www.servershop24.de/en/dell-r720-fan/a-122259/ Edit: if you seearch for PFR0612UHE you'll find a different fan, but most of them looks like they share the same connector.

@RogerMirandaPerez I meant examining the connector itself for a part number. Manufacturers like Dell like to have a part number on everything. Or you could buy another server advertised as "for spares or repair" and have a good chance of getting six connectors. I saw one on eBay for £30, but you would probably need one close enough to you to collect in person rather than paying lots for postage.

Not an exact match, but close: https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/amphenol-cs-fci/75869-330LF/1523340

I'd just replace the damn thing with a 2x2 header strip :)

In case the pitch is actually 2mm this might be one of Molex "Milli-Grid" family connectors, subfamily of BMI connectors. Not sure if they come in 2x2 however. Molex web site being godawful, so I can't find anything...

@Lundin the measure is closer to 2.5 than 2mm. Following your previous recommendation, I tried to plug the fan into one row of pins I had for my Arduino projects and it fit perfectly (so the distance must be the same as Arduino Uno boards)

Yeah scratch that, it doesn't seem to come in 2x2 anyway. Looks quite similar however.
